# elasticsearch bulk ingestion how to avoid updates

Tags: elasticsearch, bulkinsert

Within my product I use elasticsearch for storing CDRs (call them txn logs, if you will).  My transactions are asynchronous and happen at a very fast rate i.e. around 5000 txns/sec.  My transaction involves submitting request to a network entity, and later at some other point of time I receive the response.

The data ingestion technique to ES, earlier involved two phase operations viz., 1) add an entry into ES as soon as I submit to the network layer; 2) when I get response, then update the previous entry with additional status such as delivery succeeded.

I am doing this with bulk insertion method, in which the bulk records contain both inserts and updates.  As a result the ingestion is very very slow, which ended up hogging / halting my application.  Later, we changed the ingestion technique in such a way that we only insert to elastic when we get final response.  Till such time we store the data in a redis store.  But this has disadvantages of data loss and non-realtime reports.

So, I was looking at some option like having 2 indexes for the same record.  Parent index will have all data, and the child record will have delivery status.   I don't know if this is possible.  I studied about nested queries and has-child, has-parent queries.  What I am unsure is, can I insert the parent and child data at separate points in time, without having to use update.  Or should I create two different records with common txn-id without worrying about parent/child?

What is the best way?

Comment: When you mention "As a result the ingestion is very very slow", can you elaborate on how you're sending those bulks? How many docs per bulk? at what rate? etc

Comment: I am sending around 500 to 5k records in each insertion, based on how many records got accumulated in that moment.  And it takes about 10  seconds upto 3 minutes to finish the batch insertion.  However if I use only inserts it finishes 2 to 3 seconds.